# Json response from shopping cart PHP file returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest, shopping-cart

I'm working on a shopping cart. I'm using php and javascript with xmlhttprequest call for ajax side of the application.
My problem is anytime i click on the 'add to cart' button product information is sent as json type through xmlhttprequest to the php file but the php file only returns 'undefined'. The idea is to get the session count of the shopping cart.

Below is the code:

xmlhttprequest file (dodo.js):

```
function postForm(){
    var inputid = document.getElementById("product_id").value;
    var inputname = document.getElementById("product_name").value;
    var inputprice = document.getElementById("product_price").value;
    var inputdesc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
    var inputimag = document.getElementById("product_imag").value;
    //var action = "add";
    var sedd = {product_id : inputid, product_name : inputname, product_price : inputprice, product_desc : inputdesc, product_imag : inputimag};
    
    //var sedd = "product_id="+inputid+"&action="+action;
    if(ajaxConnector.readyState == 0 || ajaxConnector.readyState == 4){
        ajaxConnector.open("POST","cartprocess.php",true);
        ajaxConnector.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "json");
        ajaxConnector.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(ajaxConnector.readyState == 4 && ajaxConnector.status == 200){
                //document.getElementById("sapo").innerHTML = "<p>Sent now</p>";
                //json = JSON.parse(ajaxConnector.responseText);
                $("#cart-added-main").show(function(){
                    $("#cart-added-show").html(inputname+" added to cart");
                    $("#cart-added-main").fadeOut(8000);
                });
                document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = JSON.parse(ajaxConnector.responseText).count;
                //document.getElementById("sapo").innerHTML = ajaxConnector.responseText;
            }//else{
                //alert('Failed to add to cart.');
            //}
        }
        ajaxConnector.send(sedd);
    }
}
```

Php file (cartprocess.php) :

```
<?php
session_start();
$json = array();

if(!empty($_POST["product_id"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["cartad"])){
        $item_new_id = array_column($_SESSION["cartad"], "product_id");
        if(!in_array($_POST["product_id"], $item_new_id)){
            
            foreach($_SESSION["cartad"] as $keys => $values){
                if($values["product_id"] == $_POST[product_id]){
                    $item_new = array(
                    'product_id' => $_POST["product_id"],  
                     'product_name' => $_POST["product_name"],  
                     'product_price' => $_POST["product_price"],  
                     'product_desc' => $_POST["product_desc"],
                     'product_imag' => $_POST["product_imag"]
                    );
                
                $_SESSION["cartad"][$count] = $item_new;
                
                }
            }
            
        }else{
            $output = "Item already added";
        }
        
    }else{
        $item_new = array(
            'product_id' => $_POST["product_id"],  
             'product_name' => $_POST["product_name"],  
             'product_price' => $_POST["product_price"],  
             'product_desc' => $_POST["product_desc"],
             'product_imag' => $_POST["product_imag"]
        );
        
        $_SESSION["cartad"][0] = $item_new;
    }
        $json['count'] = count($_SESSION["cartad"]);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I would also appreciate a good ebook reference, good tutorial reference, or a good website to help me refresh knowledge on shopping cart with php and xmlhttprequest / ajax. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues here.
The first is that you're not sending json in your request, to do this you have to convert your object to json.

```
ajaxConnector.send(JSON.stringify(sedd));
```

Secondly wouldn't have read it if you sent the json. $_POST is not populated for a json request.
To get the json data you have to read it from `php://input`

```
<?php
session_start();
$json = array();

$POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); //<-- here

if(!empty($POST["product_id"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["cartad"])){
        $item_new_id = array_column($_SESSION["cartad"], "product_id");
        if(!in_array($POST["product_id"], $item_new_id)){
            
            foreach($_SESSION["cartad"] as $keys => $values){
                if($values["product_id"] == $POST[product_id]){
                    $item_new = array(
                    'product_id' => $POST["product_id"],  
                     'product_name' => $POST["product_name"],  
                     'product_price' => $POST["product_price"],  
                     'product_desc' => $POST["product_desc"],
                     'product_imag' => $POST["product_imag"]
                    );
                
                $_SESSION["cartad"][$count] = $item_new;
                
                }
            }
            
        }else{
            $output = "Item already added";
        }
        
    }else{
        $item_new = array(
            'product_id' => $POST["product_id"],  
             'product_name' => $POST["product_name"],  
             'product_price' => $POST["product_price"],  
             'product_desc' => $POST["product_desc"],
             'product_imag' => $POST["product_imag"]
        );
        
        $_SESSION["cartad"][0] = $item_new;
    }
        $json['count'] = count($_SESSION["cartad"]);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json)
```

;

Comment: Thanks Musa, but your attempt doesn't solve the problem. I don't even get feedback anymore. Please review it again. Thanks.